# Admob refresh rate between activities

Tags: android, admob

I've been uploading apps to the Google Play for a couple of months now. I've added Admob banner ads in all of my ~30apps. I'm getting my first payment this month, and I'll get a "big" one (+2000$) in January.

So, I've been doing my research. I've found AdMob closed LOTS of profitable accounts this year, so I'm a bit scared. I'm following their rules: no fraud clicks, banner always at the bottom of the app (shown in a fixed region, no matter if ad is served or not).

My only "but" is the refresh rate. Admob RECOMMENDS applying a 60 second refresh rate. I load an ad in every "onCreate" call of all my Activities. So, if an user enters my app in Activity A and Ad will be shown. If 5 seconds later, he navigates to Activity B, another Ad will be served.

I developed a while ago an static function, based on shared preferences, which doesn't allow the app to request an Ad faster than once in X seconds. That solves your problem! Nope.

Most of my aps have 4 or 5 Activities, one of them is shown 80-90% of time. I don't want the Ad to be server for an activity that is shown 2 or 3 seconds and then I wouldn't ask for another ad in the main activity because I still need to wait another 57 seconds.

I wonder how you guys solved this issue, I can't be the only want "fighting" against this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution (and a pretty good hueristic) is to just show ads in the activity that is shown 80-90% of the time. If the user is only in one of your activities for 2-3 seconds, chances are they aren't looking to click an ad in that activity. Do right by your users and don't annoy them with ads in the main menu or setting menu of your app.