# Admob's minimum request interval over different activities

Tags: android, admob

I read this from Admob's [implementation guidance](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2936217?hl=en):

> Also, if users navigate to and from pages with ads in an app over a
> short period of time, a new ad request should not be made sooner than
> the recommended 60 second rate.

Does the 60-second limitation apply to requests from a **single** activity, or across **all** activities in an app?

If it is the latter case, I believe it's technically hard to achieve as it's not how android activities and views are designed to work.

Is there a standard way to achieve it? Multiple activities with banner ads should not be uncommon, thus I feel like that I'm missing out on something.

The answer to this question [Admob refresh rate between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753416/admob-refresh-rate-between-activities) suggests to put banners on the activity that is most shown. However, the time that users spend on our app is not concentrated on a single activity.

We have just received a limited ad serving warning due to invalid traffic concerns. We believe it is caused by our application requesting for a new ad (banner) each time when the user navigates back to an activity, regardless of the interval between the last request. Now we're fixing it by only loading ads once **per activity** per process. Not sure if the change is enough to bring our implementation in line with Admob's policies. Ads could still be requested far under 60-second intervals in the worst—but not uncommon—scenario if a user opens multiple new activities within a short period. We have three activities with banners, therefore, in the worst case, 2 additional requests will be made.

We really don't want to mess up our account!

Comment: Did you get the ads back?